SPARQL query returns 0 results when querying specific value in array
I am new to RDF and SPARQL, so i want to list all the Properties that https://schema.org/ListItem can have for example. This is the turtle file for https://schema.org/version/latest/schemaorg-current-https.ttl
I am using RDFlib in python https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html
I am running this code but i get 0 results:
q =  """
    PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    
    SELECT DISTINCT ?label
    WHERE {
        ?s a rdf:Property ;
            schema:domainIncludes ?domain ;
            rdfs:label ?label .
        FILTER(?domain = "http://schema.org/ListItem")
    }
    """

for r in g.query(q):
    print(r)

When i run the query without schema:domainIncludes i get all the Properties for all schema types, like this:
    PREFIX schema: <http://schema.org/>
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
    
    SELECT DISTINCT ?label
    WHERE {
        ?s a rdf:Property ;
            rdfs:label ?label .
    }

Some Properties are using a list syntax, like this.
schema:position a rdf:Property ;
    schema:domainIncludes schema:CreativeWork,
        schema:ListItem ;

Which, as far as i ahve understood is equivalent to
schema:position a rdf:Property ;
        schema:domainIncludes schema:CreativeWork ;
        schema:domainIncludes schema:ListItem .

So i dont understand what is going wrong. is it the library or something else?

"http://schema.org/ListItem" denotes a string literal while your data does use a URI resource which either is encapsulated in angle brackets or used like the prefix form your can see in the data. So either write FILTER(?domain = <http://schema.org/ListItem>) or FILTER(?domain = schema:ListItem)

Thank you very much @UninformedUser! Using URI resource now lists all Properties for every schema type, but it should list only the few that match with schema:ListItem, and no matter what i put in filter, for example schema:ProfilePage it still lists all the Properties like there is no filter at all.

Actually i am still getting empty result set using both http://schema.org/ListItem and schema:ListItem

Your dataset is a version of Schema.org based on https protocol, thus, the URIs are all starting with https: - that means you also have to do this in your SPARQL query, i.e. `PREFIX schema: https://schema.org/
PREFIX rdf: http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#
PREFIX rdfs: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#
SELECT DISTINCT ?label
WHERE {
    ?s a rdf:Property ;
        schema:domainIncludes ?domain ;
        rdfs:label ?label .
    FILTER(?domain = <https://schema.org/ListItem>)
}`


Ohh that worked, of course dumb mistakes always when starting. So the combination of using correct resource notation <> and using correct URI(of course) worked. Do you want to post an answer? @UninformedUser

glad it works. feel free to post the answer your self - and don't forget to accept your own answer to mark it as resolved. Cheers

schema.org uses https, and correct prefix  is https://schema.org/ instead of http://schema.org/
Another issue is that query is matching with string literal instead of iri which is why it's not filtering as intended. Iri notation should be used like schema:ListItem, or http://schema.org/ListItem, instead of string literal "".
